# plsql parameterised cursor in which the parameter is user input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

here's my cursor statement

```
cursor empCur(cname varchar2) is
        select empID, name
        from employee, country
        where lower(country_name) = lower(cname);
```

and call like this

```
countryName := '&countryname';
open empCur(countryName);
fetch empCur into ...
```

The variable countryName is declared along with the cursors, and this query runs fine but no data is fetched. no idea what I'm missing here..

Comment: The snippets look valid individually. Can you add a complete test case showing how you call it and what tools you are using?

Comment: If *everything* is OK but there's no result (BTW how do you know that nothing is fetched?), then WHERE clause prevents anything to be returned (i.e. there's no country with that name. Note that you've produced Cartesian product between EMPLOYEE and COUNTRY (there's no join between them), but then you're *filtering* rows on country name so result - if any - will still be wrong.

Comment: you need to post a [mcve[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some sample data like below:
A_TBL

| ID | COL_A | COL_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IE | 01-NOV-22 | 1 |
| UK | 02-NOV-22 | 2 |
| FR | 03-NOV-22 | 3 |
| IT | 04-NOV-22 | 4 |

this code works...

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    CURSOR empCur(cname VarChar2) IS
        Select ID, COL_A, COL_B
        From A_TBL
        Where Lower(ID) = Lower(cname);
    cSet  empCur%ROWTYPE;
    countryName VarChar2(20);
Begin
    countryName := '&country';
    OPEN empCur(countryName);
    FETCH empCur Into cSet;
    CLOSE empCur;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country ID = ' || cSet.ID || '   *   Date = ' || To_Char(cSet.COL_A, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '   *   Value = ' || cSet.COL_B);
End;
--
-- returning for input 'IE'
--
-- anonymous block completed
-- Country ID = IE   *   Date = 01.11.2022   *   Value = 1
```

Did you check your cursor's FROM clause. There is no join condition between the tables employee and country. That or where condition (or both) coud be the reason that no rows were fetched...
Regards...

Comment: Thank u!!! all thanks to u i finished this on time:):) million thanks

Comment: @were  - You are wellcome. Glad you got it done.